# Shortcut for Xcode to switch to the last tab?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there are two shortcuts for switching around tabs by <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>}</kbd>.

However, I need frequently go to the first tab or last tab. Does Xcode have dedicated shortcuts for that?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be. In fact, searching Xcode's shortcuts for "tab" only yields the following results.

[image]